# Cpanel: How to check if the email function is activated - contact forms from users don't get sent to my email

Tags: forms, email, smtp, cpanel

I have a website with a contact form. 
For some reason the emails aren't getting sent to me, and the code should be fine. 
My guess is that the mailing function from Cpanel is disabled.

How can I check if it is active/disabled?

The other option is that the server isn't giving the permition to do it. I really don't know what can be the problem. Can someone help me to solve this one out?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host must have disabled nodody user mailing capabilities. In that case its better you change your code for sending emails via SMTP authentication method.

Comment: How do I do that exactly